# Form Wizards w/ React Navigation Stack and Formik

Tags: react-native, web, react-navigation, formik

For forms that are broken into steps, i generally use Formik at the root of the wizard with each step as a screen in the stack navigator.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Wizard = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        step1Field: '',
        step2Field: '',
        // Add more fields as needed
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        // Handle the global form submission logic here
        console.log('Form Values:', values);
        // You can navigate to a summary screen or perform other actions
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Step1">
        <Stack.Screen name="Step1" component={Step1Screen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Step2" component={Step2Screen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Step3" component={Step3Screen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Wizard;
```

When this component is rendered in web everything is smooth but in the react native app typing in any field is a bit laggy.
Any suggestion would help to improve this or better approach would be appreciated.

my input field and other form related components follow the following pattern

```
const Input = ({ name }) => {
  const formik = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={formik.values[name]}
      onChangeText={text => formik.setFieldValue(name, text)}
    />
  )
}
```